# Invalid HTTP endpoint specified for URI in Amazon ApiGateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am trying to create a resource /user/devices with GET method for API Gateway using cloudformation template but it is giving me a below error

An error occurred: ApiGatewayRootMethod - Invalid HTTP endpoint specified for URI (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID:xxxxxxxxxx)

Below is my cloudformation template,

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2018-11-13
Description: test user

resources:
  Resources:

    UserDeviceApiGateway:
      Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
      Properties:
        Name: "test-user-info"
        Description: "Fetch the user"

    UserResource:
      Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Resource'
      Properties:
        ParentId:
          Fn::GetAtt: ["UserDeviceApiGateway","RootResourceId"]
        RestApiId:
          Ref: "UserDeviceApiGateway"
        PathPart: 'user'

    Resource:
      Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Resource'
      Properties:
        ParentId:
          Ref: "UserResource"
        RestApiId:
          Ref: "UserDeviceApiGateway"
        PathPart: 'devices'

    ApiGatewayRootMethod:
      Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
      Properties:
        AuthorizationType: "NONE"
        HttpMethod: "GET"
        Integration:
          IntegrationHttpMethod: "GET"
          Type: "HTTP"
          Uri: Sub
            - "arn:aws:apigateway:arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxx:function:user-device-lambda/invocations"
        ResourceId:
          Fn::GetAtt: ["UserDeviceApiGateway","RootResourceId"]
        RestApiId:
          Ref: "UserDeviceApiGateway"

    Deployment:
      DependsOn:
        - ApiGatewayRootMethod
      Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment'
      Properties:
        RestApiId:
          Ref: "UserDeviceApiGateway"
        StageName: dev
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party but...

You specify `Type: "HTTP"` for `ApiGatewayRootMethod` but HTTP takes the API endpoint URL. The URI formation that you specify is taken by `Type: "AWS"`.

From AWS docs:

> The Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) for the integration.
>
> If you specify HTTP for the Type property, specify the API endpoint URL.
>
> If you specify MOCK for the Type property, don't specify this property.
>
> If you specify AWS for the Type property, specify an AWS service that follows this form: arn:aws:apigateway:region:subdomain.service|service:path|action/service_api. For example, a Lambda function URI follows this form: arn:aws:apigateway:region:lambda:path/path. The path is usually in the form /2015-03-31/functions/LambdaFunctionARN/invocations. For more information, see the uri property of the Integration resource in the Amazon API Gateway REST API Reference.
>
> If you specified HTTP or AWS for the Type property, you must specify this property.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-integration.html